# Spark Scala DataFrames Windowing To Have A WrappedArray[String] Accumulative Set

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have some code like this:

```
case class ns(name : String, age : Integer, grp : Integer)
val df = List(
  ns("sara", 45, 1),
  ns("bob", 45, 1),
  ns("lucy", 5, 2),
  ns("paul", 5, 3),
  ns("cindyluhoo", 1, 3),
  ns("simona", 45, 2)
).toDF
df.show


//+----------+---+---+
//|      name|age|grp|
//+----------+---+---+
//|      sara| 45|  1|
//|       bob| 45|  1|
//|      lucy|  5|  2|
//|      paul|  5|  3|
//|cindyluhoo|  1|  3|
//|    simona| 45|  2|
//+----------+---+---+

df.orderBy($"age", $"grp").show

//+----------+---+---+
//|      name|age|grp|
//+----------+---+---+
//|cindyluhoo|  1|  3|
//|      lucy|  5|  2|
//|      paul|  5|  3|
//|       bob| 45|  1|
//|      sara| 45|  1|
//|    simona| 45|  2|
//+----------+---+---+

df.orderBy($"grp").groupBy($"age").agg( collect_set($"name").as('lst)).as('fs).show

//+---+-------------------+
//|age|                lst|
//+---+-------------------+
//| 45|[sara, bob, simona]|
//|  1|       [cindyluhoo]|
//|  5|       [lucy, paul]|
//+---+-------------------+
```

I want this instead (age order isn't important as long as it's grouped- see output):

```
//+----------+---+---+---------------------+
//|      name|age|grp|   windowedData      |
//+----------+---+---+---------------------+
//|cindyluhoo|  1|  3| [cindyluhoo]        |
//|      lucy|  5|  2| [lucy]              |
//|      paul|  5|  3| [lucy, paul]        |
//|       bob| 45|  1| [bob]               |
//|      sara| 45|  1| [bob, sara]         |
//|    simona| 45|  2| [bob, sara, simona] |
//+----------+---+---+---------------------+
```

I know I have to window, so I test this:

```
val windowSpec = Window.partitionBy($"age").orderBy($"grp")
val indexCol =  row_number.over(windowSpec) - 1
df.withColumn("ind", indexCol).show

//+----------+---+---+---+
//|      name|age|grp|ind|
//+----------+---+---+---+
//|      sara| 45|  1|  1|
//|       bob| 45|  1|  2|
//|    simona| 45|  2|  3|
//|cindyluhoo|  1|  3|  1|
//|      lucy|  5|  2|  1|
//|      paul|  5|  3|  2|
//+----------+---+---+---+
//
```

Now, I am going to try to get the WrappedArray:

EDIT:Fixed typos on the following line:

```
val accNamesCol = lag($"name",0).over(windowSpec)
df.withColumn("ind", indexCol).withColumn("accNames", accNamesCol).show

//+----------+---+---+---+----------+
//|      name|age|grp|ind|  accNames|
//+----------+---+---+---+----------+
//|      sara| 45|  1|  1|      sara|
//|       bob| 45|  1|  2|       bob|
//|    simona| 45|  2|  3|    simona|
//|cindyluhoo|  1|  3|  1|cindyluhoo|
//|      lucy|  5|  2|  1|      lucy|
//|      paul|  5|  3|  2|      paul|
//+----------+---+---+---+----------+
```

That's not what I want, so try this:

```
df.withColumn("ind", indexCol).withColumn("accNames", collect_set(accNamesCol)).show
```

Appropriate for this forum, the last line crashes with

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:161)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.get(TreeNode.scala:57)
```

How can I get this to work with a window function? (I want the `ind` column too.)

EDIT #1: (Added Section):

For clarification, I'm looking for a way to roll up the names col. The final output should look like this:

```
//+----------+---+---+---+---------------------+
//|      name|age|grp|ind|  accNames           |
//+----------+---+---+---+---------------------+
//|      sara| 45|  1|  1| [sara]              |
//|       bob| 45|  1|  2| [sara, bob]         |
//|    simona| 45|  2|  3| [sara, bob, simona] |
//|cindyluhoo|  1|  3|  1| [cindyluhoo]        |
//|      lucy|  5|  2|  1| [lucy]              |
//|      paul|  5|  3|  2| [lucy, paul]        |
//+----------+---+---+---+---------------------+
```

EDIT #2: The last column, `accNames`, is of type `scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray[String]`.

ADDED INFO (ANOTHER EDIT):

I'm unsure if the objective can be achieved with collect_set OR involves a UDAF and would like this (Tested):

```
case class ns(name : String, age : Integer, grp : Integer)

// examples
// https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-11372
// https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-11885
class AggStringSet extends UserDefinedAggregateFunction {
  import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

  // inputSchema returns a StructType and every field of this StructType represents an input argument of this UDAF.
  override def inputSchema: StructType = StructType(StructField("value", StringType) :: Nil)
  // returns a StructType and every field of this StructType represents a field of this UDAF’s intermediate results.
  override def bufferSchema: StructType = StructType(Seq(StructField("merge", ArrayType(StringType,true),true)))
  // dataType returns a DataType representing the data type of this UDAF’s returned value
  override def dataType: DataType = ArrayType(StringType,true)

  // indicate if this UDAF always generate the same result for a given set of input values.
  override def deterministic: Boolean = true

  // used to initialize values of an aggregation buffer, represented by a MutableAggregationBuffer.
  override def initialize(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer): Unit = {
    buffer(0) = Seq[String]()
  }

  // Iterate over each entry of a group
  // update an aggregation buffer represented by a MutableAggregationBuffer for an input Row
  override def update(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer, input: Row): Unit = {
//      println("update1:" + input.getAs[String](0))
    buffer(0) = buffer.getAs[Seq[String]](0) :+ input.getAs[String](0)
//      println("update2:" + buffer(0))
//      buffer(0)
  }
  //  merge two aggregation buffers and store the result to a MutableAggregationBuffer.
  override def merge(buffer1: MutableAggregationBuffer, buffer2: Row): Unit = {
//      println("merge1: " + buffer1.getAs[Seq[String]](0))
//      println("merge2: " + buffer2.getAs[Seq[String]](0))
    buffer1(0) = buffer1.getAs[Seq[String]](0) ++ buffer2.getAs[Seq[String]](0)
  }
  // generate the final result value of this UDAF based on values stored in an aggregation buffer represented by a Row.
  override def evaluate(buffer: Row): Any = {
//      println("eval: "+ buffer.getAs[Seq[String]](0))
//      println("eval: "+ buffer.getAs[Any](0))
    buffer.getAs[Seq[String]](0)
  }
}
```

Comment: According to Databricks (see https://forums.databricks.com/answers/7965/view.html), UDAF functions fail with windowing functions in Spark 1.5 and will be available in 2.0. As for 1.6.1 has support for this or not ...